# Orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Consider the infinite dimensional vector space of functions $M$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

The inner product defined as in square integrable functions we use in quantum mechanics.

How can we show that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement gives the ***topological closure*** of the vector space and not the vector space itself?

If we already know that the orthogonal complement is itself closed.

$$M^{{\perp}{\perp}}=\overline M$$

Comment: Orthogonal complement with respect to which inner product?

Comment: Whatever the inner product, though, a good place to start is probably showing that $M^{\perp}$ is always closed.

Comment: The inner product used in quantum mechanics defined as square integrable functions $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: See corollary 21.6. (iii) on Schilling's "Measures integrals and martingales"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M \subseteq \mathcal{H}$ be a linear subspace of the Hilbert space.

(i) Consider $\{\varphi_n\}$ as a Cauchy sequence in $M$

Because $\forall \varphi_n \in M \implies \forall \mu \in M^\perp: \langle\mu, \varphi_n\rangle=0\implies \varphi_n\in (M^\perp)^\perp$

Therefore, $M \subseteq M^{\perp\perp}$

(ii)  $M^{\perp\perp}$ is an orthogonal complement and hence it is a closed linear subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.

Therefore, it is a sub Hilbert space. Hence complete. So $\{\varphi_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M^{\perp\perp}$ and hence it converges in $M^{\perp\perp}$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_n= \varphi \in M^{\perp\perp}$$

We have shown that $\{\varphi_n\}$ as a Cauchy sequence in $M$ converges to $\varphi$ in $M^{\perp\perp}$. That is the topological closure of $M$ is $M^{\perp\perp}$:

$$\overline{M}=M^{\perp\perp}$$